# How to use Java 8 Collectors groupingBy to get a Map with a Map of the collection?

Tags: java-8, java-stream, collectors

Imagine these classes

```
class Subject {
   private int id;
   private Type type;
   private String origin;
   private String name;

   Subject(int id, Type type, String origin, String name) {
      this.id = id;
      this.type = type;
      this.origin = origin;
      this.name = name;
   }

   // Getters and Setters
}

enum Type {
   TYPE1,
   TYPE2
}
```

I have a list of those Subject classes

```
List<Subject> subjects = Arrays.asList(
    new Subject(1, Type.TYPE1, "South", "Oscar"),
    new Subject(2, Type.TYPE2, "South", "Robert"),
    new Subject(3, Type.TYPE2, "North", "Dan"),
    new Subject(4, Type.TYPE2, "South", "Gary"));
```

I would like to get as a result of using `Collectors.groupingBy()` a Map grouping first the `Subject` objects by `Subject.origin` and then grouped by `Subject.type`

Getting as a result an object like this `Map<String, Map<Type, List<Subject>>>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`groupingBy` accepts a downstream collector, which can also be a `groupingBy`:

```
subjects.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(
                Subject::getOrigin, 
                groupingBy(Subject::getType)    
        ));
```

Comment: This helped me solve a similar problem: should you wish to aggregate your leaf List<X> further, the inner groupingBy can also take a downstream Collector. In my case I needed `.collect(groupingBy(DishIngredientMass::getDishId, groupingBy(DishIngredientMass::getIngredientId, summingDouble(DishIngredientMass::getCookMass))))`

Answer (score 4):

```
Stream<Subject> subjects = Stream.of(
  new Subject(1, Subject.Type.TYPE1, "South", "Oscar"), 
  new Subject(2, Subject.Type.TYPE2, "South", "Robert"),
  new Subject(3, Subject.Type.TYPE2, "North", "Dan"), 
  new Subject(4, Subject.Type.TYPE2, "South", "Gary"));




Map<String, Map<Subject.Type, List<Subject>>>  subjectByOriginByType;
subjectByOriginByType = subjects.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        s->s.getOrigin(), Collectors.groupingBy(
        s->s.getType(), 
        Collectors.mapping((Subject s) -> s, Collectors.toList()))));
```